# Dial a number using Phonegap in IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cordova

I need to Make a call to a phonenumber using a PhoneGap Application in IPhone. Here is the code that I am using which is not working
`<a href="tel:+1-800-275-2273" style="width:300px;height:67px;margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="image.png" alt="" /></a>`

Also I am using childbrowser and mapkit plugin in the app. Can anyone tell me how should I make a call using Phonegap in Iphone app ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...and what part of it is not working? If you want a good answer you need to provide more details to the exact problem.

Comment: The script tel:+1-800-275-2273 does not get called. I simply need to make a call to a phone number by clicking a image button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it (copy and paste) without an image but with just text, it tried to dial the number, so it works. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: Just checking, are you trying it out on the device? Of course, the Simulator cannot dial out so it won't work in the Simulator.

Comment: I checked it on simulator to see if Alert appears to call the number. Did you also add childbrowser and mapkit plugin ?

Comment: Like I mentioned, the Simulator does not have phone capabilites (namely the Phone.app), so no dialing available, thus tel: does not work. It doesn't matter if I add plugins or not.

Comment: Yes you are right Shazron. I got confused due to Alert dialog that comes for confirmation of calling.

Answer (score 4):

This just worked for me:

```
window.location.href='tel:800-123-4567';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out to if you are having problems in iOS 5. This allows you to call a phone via javascript. https://github.com/j-mcnally/PhoneGap-ios-PhoneDialer

Answer (score 2):

After the `tel:`, try using numerals only, i.e.

> <a href="tel:18002752273"><img src="image.png" alt="" /></a>