# How to use images instead of plain text as links for mobile safari on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile, xhtml, safari

I am encountering problems with using images instead of plain text as links for mobile Safari on iOS5, tested on device. I have tried three different link protocols, tel: mailto: and http: and describe the problem for each below.

```
<a href="tel:1234"><img src="images/phone.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Does not work in iOS5, it throws an Cannot Open Page error, but works with text as link.

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com"><img src="images/mail.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Does work and fires up the mail app.

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com"><img src="images/home.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Works as expected.

**However**, the 'touch-and-hold' event, which pops up with normal text links works differently for images. For mailto links this is New Message/Add to Contacts/Copy/Cancel and for tel links it is Call/Add to Contacts/Copy/Cancel.
With image links, the pop-up gives the options Open/Save Image/Copy/Cancel for both the mailto and tel links, with the Open option failing for tel links "because the address is invalid".

For my website, I would like to include my email and phone details, with the ability to mail/call directly, or to add it to the contacts. I found a related and unresolved question here:
[Dial a number using Phonegap in IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262289/dial-a-number-using-phonegap-in-iphone/8314534#8314534)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Curiously, when saved to the home screen on an iOS device, and ran as a web-app, the touch-and-hold gesture results in no popup at all for the image links, whereas the text links work fine.
(To enable a website to be run as a web-app, I added the following code in the head of the page:)

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Can anybody reproduce this behaviour using the above link, and have clues which versions of iOS may be affected? I tested it on iPodTouch iOS 5.0.1 and iPad iOS 4.3.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this same problem. To work around it, I used a CSS `background-image` instead of an `img` tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tel { 
        width: 102px; 
        height: 32px; 
        display: inline-block; 
        background: url(phone.png); 
    }
</style>

<a class="phone" href="tel:+1-000-000-0000"><span class="tel"></span></a>
```

Note that I specifically leave *no* whitespace inside of the `a` tag because otherwise the iPhone shows it next to the image (it appears for me as an empty underline, but this depends on your own CSS).

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro your image link failure on iOS 5.0.1.  Specifically, I put the following line into a webpage on apache:

```
<p>This is a test of a tel link: <a href="tel:2060000000"><img src="/iPodTouch_s4.png"></a></p>
```

A touch on the graphic brings up the phone dialog, with Cancel and Call options.

Touch-and-hold on the graphic presents Open in Phone, Save Image and Copy; touching Open in Phone brings up the phone dialog, again with Cancel and Call options.

The only way I can reproduce your experience is by mistyping the protocol designator. For example, this reproduces everything you mention (note the 1 instead of lowercase L in the href):

```
<p>This is a test of a tel link: <a href="te1:2060000000"><img src="/iPodTouch_s4.png"></a></p>
```

Are you positive there's no mistyping or other issue with the link?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It led me to consider three possible reasons why my link is failing.
1. (x)html: Since you wrote your img tag as html (no closing tag) and I used xhtml, I tried the links in html, but saw the same behaviour as before.
2. iDevice: I have tried it on iPodTouch (5.0.1) and iPad (4.3.3). I know you can't make calls, but with plain text links I can save to contacts, which I can't with image links. Which device did you test on?
3. Since I'm not in the US, I'm using the international format, i.e. href="tel:+4512345678". However I get the same error when removing the "+".

Comment: Otherwise, I'm pretty sure I didn't mistype anything. Actually, I have done a little test where I linked both text and image:
`<a href="tel:+4512345678">Call<img src="images/phone.jpg" alt="" /></a>` 
If I click on the text, it works as expected, but when I click on the image it doesn't, so I'm positive the actual href="tel:..." part is working.

Comment: I have the same issue. all good with text, but invalid with images.